# Let $K_1(0) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: \|x\|_2 < 1\}$ and $S := K_1(0) \setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$. Is M path connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

The Assignment:

> Let $K_1(0) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: \|x\|_2 < 1\}$ and $S := K_1(0) \setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$. Is S path connected? Explain your answer.

I don't think S is path-connected since we're removing an infinite amount of points from the path-connected $K_1(0)$. I think I should assume that it is path-connected and thus for every $x,y \in S$ there's a continuous function $\gamma$ with $\gamma(x)=0$ and $\gamma(y)=1$, but I cannot find the contradiction.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: So you are saying if i remove infinitely many points from a path connected space i will be left with a space which is not path connected

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik That's the way I'm picturing it. I don't have a theorem proving my assertion, but I think it does make a difference if you remove infinitely or finitely many points. If only finitely many points of a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are removed, the subset will still easily be path-connected.

Comment: and why is it so?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik What now?

Comment: I have asked a question.. why do you think if you remove finitely many points you will be left with path connected space?

Comment: Well, if I take two arbitrary points in a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which was formerly path connected and draw the line between them, I might get into trouble if one of the points between them was removed. But since every arbitrary ball around my removed point without my removed point is path connected, there is a continuous function "around" the removed point for the two arbitrary points.

Comment: now... do the same for countably many points... see that i can have uncountably many lines passing through a point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $S$ is path-connected.

See [How is $\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb Q^2$ path connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748103/how-is-mathbb-r2-setminus-mathbb-q2-path-connected?rq=1)